# Excluding default type name when serializing sealed type heirarchy with Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

Using [jackson-module-kotlin support for tagged unions](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/239) I define a sealed type heirarchy:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type", defaultImpl = Default::class)
sealed interface Definition {
    @JsonTypeName("default")
    data class Default(val myField: String) : Definition

    @JsonTypeName("nondefault")
    data class NonDefault(val myOtherField: Int) : Definition
}

data class Container(val definitions: List<Definition>)
```

### Deserialisation

With `defaultImpl` specified I can omit `type: "default"` from a YAML document:

```kotlin
val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory().disable(USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID)).registerKotlinModule()
println(mapper.readValue<Container>("""
        |---
        |definitions:
        |- myField: "myValue"
        |- type: "nondefault"
        |  myOtherField: 123""".trimMargin()))
```

prints:

```
Container(definitions=[Default(myField=myValue), NonDefault(myOtherField=123)])
```

### Serialisation

But Jackson still includes `type: "default"` when serialising back again:

```kotlin
println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Container(listOf(Default("myValue"),NonDefault(123)))))
```

prints:

```yaml
---
definitions:
- type: "default"
  myField: "myValue"
- type: "nondefault"
  myOtherField: 123
```

How can Jackson be configured to omit `type: "default"`?  (Testing confirmed that `JsonInclude(NON_DEFAULT)` doesn't apply to the `type field)